# FineUpload - deleting local copy of uploaded image

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, fine-uploader

I'm using fineupload S3 in an angular mobile web application to handle the capture and upload of images from the device camera.

I have a requirement to make sure that the captured images are not displayed in the device gallery and not stored on the device. *(image and video)*

The deleteFile function of fineupload doesn't appear to handle this task and it instead looks like its designed to delete the uploaded file from the server.

So i'm looking for a solution to either prevent the device from storing the captured images in the first place or to delete the files once they've been uploaded.

Comment: Save it as a custom type. Most other apps will be unable or wont even try to open images without an extension. Encode it as base64, then save it as `*.dat` file.

Comment: does fine uploader have an option to save a photo/video as a custom file name? The documentation doesn't seem to answer that question.
The other strange thing is that on some android models, it is only the captured videos that are stored on the device... images dont get stored.
Model GT P5110 with android version 4.2.2 stores both photos and videos, model SM T330 with android 4.4.2 stores only videos

Comment: David, as far as programs go, the camera apps behave very differently. When taking a screenshot, a file is usually kept in refference as the taken picture, if its going to be auto-saved or not, depends on that app. If you have an app that takes a picture, you can then use the camera Intent to delete the picture afterwards, but, if you are using someone else app, then, the other app behavior is executed, and usually cannot/should not be controlled by you...

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I think you have confirmed my thoughts and this is just not possible to control from a web app. The varying results im seeing must just be quirks of the different devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the browser (either mobile or desktop) does not have the privileges to manipulate the file system. If your using cordova/phonegap you should try removing the photo with the file system API provided by them.